# Can't open file when debugging x86 NASM program with GDB

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, nasm

Here is a simplified example of reading file from my code:

```
section .data
    filename db 'txt.txt', 0x00

section .bss
    fd resd 0x01
    buff resb 0x100

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; open file
    mov eax, 0x05     ; SYS_OPEN
    mov ebx, filename
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov edx, 0o400    ; r--------
    int 0x80

    ; check if file was opened successfully
    cmp eax, 0x00
    js _exit
    
    mov [fd], eax    ; copy file descriptor

    ; read file
    mov eax, 0x03    ; SYS_READ
    mov ebx, [fd]
    mov ecx, buff
    mov edx, 0x100
    int 0x80

    ; close file
    mov eax, 0x06    ; SYS_CLOSE
    mov ebx, [fd]
    int 0x80

_exit:
    mov eax, 0x01    ; SYS_EXIT
    mov ebx, 0x00
    int 0x80
```

When I compile and run the program, the file is read successfully, but when I start the debugging process through GDB, after opening the file there is a negative number in the `eax` register, not a file descriptor, which indicates an error

Comment: Run your code with `strace`. This reveals the error code returned by SYS_OPEN.

Comment: It shows that after calling sys_open a file descriptor (3) is returned, apparently the problem is in the gbd

Comment: "0o620    ; octal 400" is wrong. Octal 400 is `0o400`

Comment: I meant that octal 620 is decimal 400

Comment: IDK why it would be useful to write a mode in decimal when you already have it in octal, since you want it in 3 bit groups.  `0o620` is `rw--w----`.  Normally when opening a file with `O_CREAT`, use `0o666` and let the user's `umask` mask away the write-for-other and maybe the write-for-group bits.  But you're not passing `O_CREAT`, only `O_RDONLY` (ecx=0), so the mode bits never matter.  You might as well leave EDX unset.  But if you're going to set it to anything, `0o620` makes little sense.  Write-only for group?

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: Were you running GDB from a different directory or something, where there wasn't a `txt.txt`?  Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, not necessarily the directory with the source or executable.

Comment: I was running GDB from inside a folder with my txt.txt file. But specifying full path to the file helped, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еhe problem was that it was necessary to specify the full path to the file to open when running GDB e.g. `${fileDirname}/<filename>`